# floatingscroll on datatable .net

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I need a horizontal scoll bar on my datatable however I cant have the users needing to scroll to the bottom each time to scroll. Could someone give me and example of [floatingscroll](https://github.com/Amphiluke/jquery-plugins/tree/master/src/floatingscroll) working with a datatable from [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made use of the init and update functions on the floating scroll. The init on document ready and the update in the draw event